# Exporting an array to Excel

Tags: php, sql, arrays, excel

I'm trying to export an array of arrays to excel.  I have it set up to be a header variable, and a data variable that basically builds a giant string to be executed in the export.  However, only the header variable is going through.  Let me show some code:

This is setting the parameters:

```php
    str_replace(" ", "_", $getData['name']);
    $filename = $getData['name']."_summary.xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/x-msdownload");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
```

Which goes to a function to get the information:

```php
foreach($tempRS as $key=>$value)
{
    foreach($value as $iKey=>$iValue)
    {
        if($count == 6)
        {
            $iValue = str_replace('"', '""', $iValue);
            $iValue = '"'.$iValue.'"'."\n";
            $data .= trim($iValue);
            $count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $iValue = str_replace('"', '""', $iValue);
            $iValue = '"'.$iValue.'"'."\t";
            $data .= trim($iValue);
            $count++;
        }
    }

}
$header = "ROW HEADER 1\tROW HEADER 2\tROW HEADER 3\tROW HEADER 4\tROW HEADER 5\tROW HEADER 6\n";
print "$header\n$data";
```

I can't seem to figure out why i'm losing the $data variable on the export.

Comment: where is $data being defined?  Is it possible that $data has gone out of scope?

Comment: I've echoed data after that foreach loop to make sure it contains the data that i want it to contain.  Otherwise, i clear $data before it enters the loops and do nothing to it afterwards.

Comment: So you can echo the data?  Doesn't that solve your problem?  Or is it only a problem when the headers are set?

Comment: It's not displaying in Excel.  I can echo it to the webpage, but not into the excel document.  Only the $headers show up in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `fputcsv()` to generate that CSV data for you? Or better yet, instead of making a .csv masquerade as an Excel file, you can use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to output a native .xls/.xlsx and actually use formatting and formulae in the generated spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, use echo instead of print. Print causes loads of overhead as it does both return and echo the data.

Secondly, don't put the variables within quotes, use

```
echo $header ."\n".$data;
```

To get to your question, does the foreach loops actually loop? Have you checked the $data if it contains any data?

A better solution might be this:

```
$header = '';
echo $header;

foreach() loop here {
    //echo the data here instead of putting it in a variable
}
```

Or maybe better, use http://nl.php.net/fputcsv

Comment: Yeah, i've traced to make sure that the $data variable actually holds what i want it to hold.  It just doesn't get put into excel,  which is the issue i'm having.

Comment: *"Print causes loads of overhead"* - LOL.

Comment: Also, changing to echo and separating out the echo like you have, still doesn't work.

Comment: alright, I was wrong about overhead. But it is a little bit slower :)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it seems that your `trim()` method is trimming your `\n` and `\t`.

If you remove it, your code should be fine.

Here's my code to export a array of product in excel.

**Only one little problem with this code : Excel doesn't want to open it because of a format problem, but if you click "yes" when it promps an error message, you'll be ok...**

**No problem with open office though**

*Working on a fix...*

```
$filename = "products_exports " . date("Y-m-d H_i_s") . ".xls";

/**
 * Tell the browser to download an excel file.
 */

header("Content-Type: application/x-msdownload; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");


/**
 * The header of the table
 * @var string
 */
$header = "";
/**
 * All the data of the table in a formatted string
 * @var string
 */
$data = "";

//We fill in the header
foreach ($productArray as $i => $product) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($product as $key => $value) {

        if($count == count((array)new Product("")) - 1){
            $header.= $key;
        }
        else{
            $header.= $key . "\t";
            $count++;
        }
    }

    break; /*One loop is enough to get the header !*/
}


//And then the data by the product and all the categories

/*Where $productArray = This can be your custom array of object. eg.
  array[0] = new YouCustomObject(your params...);
*/
foreach ($productArray as $i => $product) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
        if($count == count((array)new Product("")) - 1){
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\n";
            $data .= $value;
            $count = 0;
        }
        else{
            $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            $data .= $value;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

echo $header ."\n". $data;
```